# Unable to Successfully Build New Project on Android Studio 3.3 with Androidx Artifacts?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.3

Recently I updated my android studio 3.2.1 to 3.3, Now I want to create new or existing project in android studio 3.3 but gradle sync failed each time i create a new project

Things i tried to sort out this problem

- Remove .gradle and .idea folder from root project and rebuild

- Also Does invalid caches/restart android studio

- Above solutions applied by searching on stackoverflow, but none of them work here

**App Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0- 
alpha4'
}
```

**Project Gradle**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

When I build project it is showing gradle sync failed with following cause :

**Cause: org/gradle/api/publish/ivy/internal/IvyServices$BuildServices**

I just want to build succesfully new project or existing project